# How to turn on indictor of center of rotation

Tags: 3d-view, customization

Sorry, I don't know what this thing is called or how to turn it on.

Here's what I know: I use Blender on a Mac Studio and also on a MacBook Pro. On the Mac Studio, in the center of the 3D viewport is a tiny bluish dot. If I place the origin of an object on the blue dot (usually I view down first and adjust, then switch to a side view and adjust that; rarely I also need to do a third adjustment), then the viewport image rotates around the origin of the object. Having the blue dot is very useful for letting me place the object within the view window so I can rotate the object without it changing position.

However, on my MacBook Pro, there is no bluish dot.

I assume that some time I was fooling around in the Blender preferences on my Mac Studio and I turned the blue dot on and it's been on ever since. If I knew where that preference was, I'd turn it on on my MacBook Pro. But I've gone into the preferences on several occassions now, and I just can't find it. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Does anybody know what this thing is called and how to turn it on or off?